# javascript to color row in table based on time value in cell

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've got a table that is auto generated by software out of my control.  I insert it into my page.  I need help with a script I can put in the head of my page that can highlight an entire row in red in the table if the current time of day is between the start time and end time columns of a row.

The one caveat is that I cannot modify the table html at all.  Which is to say, I cannot even give the table or any of the columns an id.  However, it is ok if the javascript affects all tables on the page, as this is the only table on the page.

```
<table><thead><tr><th>Subject</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Location</th><th>Organizer</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>test event 1</td><td>02/12/2020 10:00 AM</td><td>02/12/2020 06:00 PM</td><td>zoom Meeting</td><td>me</td></tr><tr><td>test event 2</td><td>02/12/2020 11:30 AM</td><td>02/12/2020 12:30 PM</td><td>wherever</td><td>you</td></tr><tr><td>test event 3</td><td>02/12/2020 12:00 PM</td><td>02/12/2020 01:00 PM</td><td>zoom Meeting</td><td>them</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

```html
<table><thead><tr><th>Subject</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Location</th><th>Organizer</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>test event 1</td><td>02/12/2020 10:00 AM</td><td>02/12/2020 06:00 PM</td><td>zoom Meeting</td><td>me</td></tr><tr><td>test event 2</td><td>02/12/2020 11:30 AM</td><td>02/12/2020 12:30 PM</td><td>wherever</td><td>you</td></tr><tr><td>test event 3</td><td>02/12/2020 12:00 PM</td><td>02/12/2020 01:00 PM</td><td>zoom Meeting</td><td>them</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: so grab the rows of the table read cells 2 and 3. convert the text to a date, check to see if itis in range, set the class of the tr so it can have background color. document.querySelectorAll and querySelector are your friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const start_tds =  document.querySelectorAll("tr > td:nth-child(2)");
   const end_tds =  document.querySelectorAll("tr > td:nth-child(3)");
   
   const len = Math.min( start_tds.length, end_tds.length );
   const today = new Date();
   


   for( let i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
       
    start_time = toDate( start_tds[ i ].textContent ) ;
    end_time =   toDate(end_tds[ i ].textContent );

    if ( today > start_time && today < end_time  ) {
        document.querySelector("tbody > tr:nth-child(" + ( i + 1 ) + ")").classList.add("red");
    }
    
   }



   function toDate( str ) {
    // 02/12/2020 10:00 AM start_tds[ i ].textContent
    const date_parts = str.split("/")
    const d = date_parts[1] + "/" + date_parts[0] + "/" + date_parts[2];
    return new Date( d );
   }
```

```css
.red {
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Subject</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Location</th><th>Organizer</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>test event 1</td><td>02/12/2020 10:00 AM</td><td>02/12/2020 06:00 PM</td><td>zoom Meeting</td><td>me</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test event 2</td><td>02/12/2020 11:30 AM</td><td>02/12/2020 09:30 PM</td><td>wherever</td><td>you</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test event 3</td><td>02/12/2020 12:00 PM</td><td>02/12/2020 01:00 PM</td><td>zoom Meeting</td><td>them</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```